# Parametric equations of cycloid on a Ramp

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, classical-mechanics

A small wheel of radius r is situated at the top of a ramp having an angle θ = π/3
rad as it appears in the ﬁgure below. At t = 0 the wheel is at rest and then it starts
to rotate clockwise in the positive x direction with constant angular velocity ω.

Find the parametric equations of the x and y coordinates of the point p as a function of time, for t>0. Using Pythagoras’ theorem or otherwise verify your formulas at the points $x_p$(T) and $y_p$(T), where T = 2π/ω.
the circle is standing on (0,0) origin and You can imagine as if the the circle is moving on the Ramo

I want to find parametric equations of the point P.

I know how to find the parametric of cycloid on x-axis when its touching the x-axis but really stuck with this one i have 2 problems with this its on a Ramp and the point P is not on the Ramp Completely lost 
please help as much as you can any hints tips appreciated and full answer would be awesome

If you are voting to close the question please leave comment why so with a reason I dont see why this question is off topic

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hint rolling ball.
http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclo%C3%AFde
( in dutch but the equation matters )

Comment: How much time does it take to get down ? that might help too.

Comment: @mick I know how to Prove cycloid on X-axis and when the point is at origin as i said in the question I want to know how to do on a Ramp

Comment: Well basicly its just an acceleration on an angle , the rest is the same ...

Comment: Could you show me please I am lost I cant get it to work

Comment: The proof i know would usually work around based on P being at origin  and circle rolling  the X-axis but this one doesn't

Comment: Not sure what you want here.  If you want to model even an approximate physics problem, the wheel does not rotate at a constant rate due to gravity.  Further, the rate at which the wheel accelerates down the plane depends on whether the wheel is a disk or a ring, or even something in between.  If not, and you just want the parametric equations of a rolling wheel moving at a constant speed, why not just look at the horizontal case and rotate coordinates?

Comment: It is moving at constant speed I know how to do the horizantal case but where the pint should be at origin but in this this is the point i want is not touching.

Comment: @RonGordon Assuming i know how to do parametric for horizontal would you be kind enough write the rest as answer for me please pleaseeeeeee Thanks

Comment: If the ring is still moving at the constant speed, why not try to find the coordinate transformation from this to the horizontal view?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang The proof i know for cycloid is when the point P is at the origin and its rolling on X-axis. But this one the line we have is not where the circle is rolling the centre is travelling on this line. and The point P is starting of at a different place I am really lost on how to transform the co-ordinates would you please write a short answer for Transform part assuming i know x=r(a-sina) and y=r(1-cosa) where a is angle and these are standard cycloid ofcourse can you show me the rest please i.e. Just transformation Thanks

Comment: According to your figure the initial part of $P$'s movement will be on  a circle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parametric equation of a cycloid generated by rolling a wheel of radius $a$ at a constant rate by an angle $\theta$ is

$$x = a (\theta-\sin{\theta}) \quad y=a (1-\cos{\theta})$$

Rotating the $(x,y)$ coordinate system to a new coordinate system $(x',y')$ by an angle $\phi$ is accomplished by the tranformation

$$x'=x \cos{\phi}+y \sin{\phi} \quad y'=-x \sin{\phi}+y \cos{\phi}$$

so that the equation of the cycloid here is, after some simplification:

$$x'=a (\sin{\phi}+\theta \cos{\phi}) - a \sin{(\theta+\phi)} \quad y' = a(\cos{\phi}-\theta \sin{\phi}) - a \cos{(\theta+\phi)}$$

Note this assume that the point $P$ begins on the ramp.  Note also that $\phi = \pi/2-\alpha$, the angle of incline.

Here is a plot for a constant rate at the specified angle of incline, $\alpha=\pi/3$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I understand this bit now. But  how do i get the Parametric for P where it is as per diagram

Comment: what would be angle $\Phi$ here is it $\pi$/3

Comment: @Jam: here it would be $\pi/2-\pi/3 = \pi/6$

Comment: Thanks how do i approach the P as its not on the Ramp at the beginning

Comment: Notice however that in the picture of the OP we notice that the ball is not tangent to the line of the wedge. Hence for a while the point $P$ rotates around the tip of the wedge until the wheel becomes tangent. Then the curve is the cycloid.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you can write cycloid equation $x=x(t),y=y(t)$, on the horizontal line with the origin as starting point. Then the first step is to rotate the line $\theta=\frac\pi3$ clockwisely using $$x'(t)=x(t)\cos\theta+y(t)\sin\theta\\ y'(t)=-x(t)\sin\theta+y(t)\cos\theta$$
The next step, the point $P$, in another view, seems like it has been rotated $\pi-\theta$ before it goes $(0,2r)$. So the parameterize equation is
$$x''(t)=x'(t+(\pi-\theta))\\y''(t)=y'(t+(\pi-\theta))$$